# Removing a widget by invoking from a button which is set using QSplitter() in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qsplitter

I want to make the "**Application 1**" disappear when the "**Single**" button is clicked. And **show it again** i mean both when "**Split**" button is clicked. Is there any method to make **disappear/collapse a widget** from **QSplitter()**.

Here's the basic layout :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QWidget` has functions `show()` and `hide()`, if Application1 is inside `QWidget` or any other widget inheriting `QWidget`, you can call `hide` on the object of that widget when user clicks on `Single` button, (`widget.hide()`). When user clicks on `Split` button you can call `show()` on the same object to show the widget.

**Edit**

Another way of achieving this would be:

to set the size of `QSplitter`. When `Single` Button is pressed, do the following:

```
splitter.setSizes([self.width(), 0])
```

When `split` button is pressed do the following:

```
splitter.setSizes([self.width()/2, self.width()/2])
```

Assuming that the `self` refer to mainWindow containing the splitter and `self.width()` gives the width of mainWindow.

Comment: The first method is usually preferable. The downside of the second method is that the current postion of the splitter is lost, so yet more code would be required to save and restore it.